# Sample size of a binomial experiment

Tags: probability

How can I calculate the required sample size to estimate a parameter within +/- 0.02 with 99% confidence (the probability of success is unknown).

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact approach, but there are plenty of very good approximate methods.

A simple, conservative approach would be to assume $p=0.5$, which will maximize the variance. Then, use the normal approximation to the sample average of a binomial expermient

$$\hat p := \frac{S}{n} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4n}\right)$$

The Z-score for the upper $99.5\%$ percentile is 2.58, so you want to solve:

$$\frac{2.58}{\sqrt{n}}=.02 \implies n= 50\times2.58 \approx 130$$

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, the true binomial parameter is either 1 or 0 and you will get either all successes or all failures. In that case, you can use the so-called Wilson confidence interval or there are other methods as well, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval for several different methods for getting a confidence interval. You can plug in your desired confidence bounds and solve for sample size $n$ to figure out the required sample size.